# Laravel 5.5 - http_build_query() is not accepting json object

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have the following collection:

```
Collection {#409 ▼
   #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#399 ▼
         +"id": 11
         +"user_id": 1
         +"name": "Job Alert"
         +"criteria": "{"languages": "3", "employerTypes": "1,2"}"
         +"status": "Active"
         +"frequency": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

In my blade template I want to build url from the criteria as follows:

```
@foreach($jobAlerts as $alert)
       <a href="/jobs{{!empty($alert->criteria)  ? '?'.http_build_query($alert->criteria) : ''}}">Preview</a>
@endforeach
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given
```

As you can see from the collection the criteria is clearly an object. So why is it throwing this error and how do i fix?

Comment: Could it be that criteria is a string?

Comment: Try `http_build_query(json_decode($alert->criteria))`

Comment: @RolandStarke you're probably right. the following seems to fix it `http_build_query(json_decode($alert->criteria, true))`